# How do I move my mask independently of my layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to move my image without having my layer mask move with it. How do I move the image without moving the mask?

See the images below for a visual depiction.

[image]

Is it possible to move just the image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make only the image move you should unlink the mask to the layer by removing the chain icon in the layer panel. This way, the mask and layer move independently of each other.

[image: Blue Overlay Example]