# How do you move just the selection box without moving the pixels in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I have a simple selection box around an icon. I want to keep the selection exactly the same size and move it to the right. How can I drag the selection box without moving the pixels with it?

It's exactly this question from photoshop: [How do I move my mask independently of my layer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20167/how-do-i-move-my-mask-independently-of-my-layer)

I've tried holding ALT and drag, which appears to be what I want based on the icon, but on linux mint holding ALT drags the whole window around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top line of the Move tool options (like most transform tools) has a three icons, that correspond to:

- `Layer` (the usual, applies to the layer or the selected pixels)
- `Selection` (applies to the selection mask, which is what you want)
- `Path` (applies to the active path)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If Alt+drag moves your whole window, then your window manager is interfering - you can usually disable this or change the modifier key in the window manager or system settings, though.

There is [an answer covering several different window managers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging) over at the AskUbuntu stack.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you have to first left-click on the selection box such that the 4 corners of the selection box become squares. Then dragging it is simply the normal left-mouse drag.

Comment: This only applies  while you are creating the selection (and AFAIK you don't need to left-click, just click&drag inside the selection).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is "Transform Selection" on the selection menu.